# JBPM Rest call to Create Repository doesn't work

Tags: rest, repository, jbpm

I am trying to create a repository with rest call

type: POST
url : http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/repositories/
body: 
{
  "name":"new-repo",
  "description":"new project",
  "userName":null,
  "password":null,
  "requestType":"new",
  "gitURL":null
}
authorization: basic Auth

but the outcome of this call is

WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-16) failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at org.guvnor.rest.backend.ProjectResource.checkOrganizationalUnitExistence(ProjectResource.java:589) [guvnor-rest-backend-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
    at org.guvnor.rest.backend.ProjectResource.createOrCloneRepository(ProjectResource.java:194) [guvnor-rest-backend-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
    at org.guvnor.rest.backend.ProjectResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.createOrCloneRepository(Unknown Source) [guvnor-rest-backend-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
....................

Answer (score 0):

Something that does not clarify the documentation

you miss organizational unit (organizationalUnitName).

This works for my

POST http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/repositories

HEADERS:
Content-Type application/json

Body:

```
{
  "name": "pruebaRest",
  "description": "prueba",
  "gitURL": "git://pruebaRest",
  "userName":"youuser",
  "password":"youpass",
  "requestType":"new",
```

> ```
>   "organizationalUnitName": "demo"
> ```

```
}
```

if it works for you, you can close https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPM-4951  ;)

I hope to help